# Add column to dataframe and merge

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframes, I need to merge using one to one, I can not use concat or any other method it must be one to one merge.

dfa does not have a matching column name to dfb

```
dfa({"CD Number": [1,2,3],"CD Name": [1 area, 2 area, 3 area],"2010      Population": [100,200,300]})

dfb({"Community Board": [01 a ,02 b ,03 c]
```

CD Number from dfa and Community Board from dfb are alike in that they both represent the same thing just using different values

So I need a new dataframe that has Community Board, CD Name and 2010      Population

I have been able to get the result I want to using the below code, but I don't it is correct and not a one to one join due to the code below

```
df2['Community Board'] = cdf1
```

I don't know if the merge is actually doing anything
    df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2)

The code I have is this but as I said, I don't think the merge is working

```
def b4():
"""Your code here.  Include appropriate comments."""


test = (dfa['CD Number'].astype(str))
cdf1 = pd.Series(dfb['Community Board'].sort_values().unique())
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Community Board':cdf1})
cd1 = pd.Series(dfa['CD Name'])
cd2 = pd.Series(dfa['2010 Population'])
cd3 = test.str.zfill(2)
#cd3 = pd.Series(dfa['CD Number'])
#'Community Board':cd3,
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Community Board':cd3,'CD Name':cd1,'2010 Population':cd2})
#df2.insert(1,'Community Board', 'default value 2')
df2['Community Board'] = cdf1
df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2)
return df3
```

I am expecting to get a dataframe that looks like

```
Community Board CD Name 2010 Population 
           01 a       1 area        100
           02 b       2 area        200
           03 a       3 area        300
```

I have tried commenting out

```
df2['Community Board'] = cdf1
```

all I get is

```
 Community Board CD Name 2010 Population
```

From what I understand that would mean that an inner join is not finding anything to match so I added

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2, how='outer')
```

and now I get

```
 Community Board CD Name 2010 Population
            01 a     nan             nan
            02 b     nan             nan
            03 c     nan             nan
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, I needed to concat cd number and cd name to create a new column to match that of the Community Board column in dfb then do the join